# How to make a list of tuples from several lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 3 lists:

```
a = [0, 1, 2]
b = [3, 4, 5]
c = [6, 7, 8]
```

And I need to create a list of tuples from them.

The output should look like this:

```
[(0, 3, 6), (1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8)]
```

Comment: This looks like you want us to do your homework. Add some code to show what you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
>>> a,b,c =[0, 1, 2],[3, 4, 5],[6, 7, 8]
>>> [(i,j,k) for i,j,k in zip(a,b,c)]
[(0, 3, 6), (1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8)]
```

Comment: @ЕвгенияРубанова You are welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it cleared your question.

Answer (score 3):

Just using `zip` only.

```py
a = [0, 1, 2]
b = [3, 4, 5]
c = [6, 7, 8]

zipped = list(zip(a, b, c))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so:

`list(zip(a, b, c))`